# Recursive Dataframe operations

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

In my spark application I would like to do operations on a dataframe in a loop and write the result to hdfs.

pseudocode:

```
var df = emptyDataframe
for n = 1 to 200000{
  someDf=read(n)
  df = df.mergeWith(somedf)
}
df.writetohdfs
```

In the above example I get good results when "mergeWith" does a unionAll.

However, when in "mergeWith" I do a (simple) join, the job gets really slow (>1h with 2 executors with 4 cores each) and never finishes (job aborts itself).

In my scenario I throw in ~50 iterations with files that just contain ~1mb of text data.

Because order of merges is important in my case, I'm suspecting this is due to the DAG generation, causing the whole thing to be run at the moment I store away the data.

Right now I'm attempting to use a .persist on the merged data frame but that also seems to go rather slowly.

**EDIT:**

As the job was running i noticed (even though I did a count and .persist) the dataframe in memory didn't look like a static dataframe.
It looked like a stringed together path to all the merges it had been doing, effectively slowing down the job linearly.

Am I right to assume the `var df` is the culprit of this?

[image: spiraling out of controle]

*breakdown of the issue as I see it:*

```
dfA = empty
dfC = dfA.increment(dfB)
dfD = dfC.increment(dfN)....
```

When I would expect DF' A C and D are object, spark things differently and does not care if I persist or repartition or not.
to Spark it looks like this:

```
dfA = empty
dfC = dfA incremented with df B
dfD = ((dfA incremented with df B) incremented with dfN)....
```

**Update2**

To get rid of the persisting not working on DF's I could "break" the lineage when converting the DF to and RDD and back again.
This has a little bit of an overhead but an acceptable one (job finishes in minutes rather than hours/never)
I'll run some more tests on the persisting and formulate an answer in the form of a workaround.

**Result:**
This only seems to fix these issues on the surface. In reality I'm back at square one and get OOM exceptions`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: It's unclear to me what this `mergeWith`-function is supposed to do (you write both union and join). Could you include the code of `mergeWith`?

Comment: the `mergeWith` function can be many things, when it's just a `union all` I get good results. 

or it could be something like this:
`SELECT f.* FROM full f LEFT OUTER JOIN delta i ON CONCAT (f.a, f.b) = CONCAT(i.a,i.z) WHERE CONCAT(i.a,i.z) IS NULL UNION ALL SELECT d.* FROM delta d`

Comment: Well there is a HUGE difference between doing a `union` and doing a `join`. For `union` Spark simply have to write the appended data, while for `join` is has to shuffle data around. Depending on the size of your data of course doing a `join` could easily case OOM-exceptions - especially since you are running on a tiny cluster.

Comment: BTW - why is it necessary for you to do this merge one file at the time. Why don't you just read in all the data, and then do your transformations?

Comment: I need this in the specific order because the files contain updates over time that need to be overwritten

Comment: also, I' not running on a tiny cluster at all, the incremental files I have to work with are small.

Comment: Is `(a mergeWith b) mergeWith c == a mergeWith (b mergeWith c)`? Then you should be able to run them in parallel, no need for linearity. And it also forms a `Monoid` with `emptyDataframe`.

Comment: I have lot's of small files that could contain the same schema. The file's timestamp is in the name of the file. An added difficulty is that these files are not on HDFS yet and my job has to fetch it first. The order of updating the rows is of importance or the data would be wrong. That's the reason I do it iteratively.
(i.e. val A -> "hello", update at 1AM -> "bye" , update at 9PM "good evening") The last update has to be "good evening" not "bye".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following is what I ended up using. It's performant enough for my usecase, it works and does not need persisting.

It is *very much* a workaround rather than a fix.

```
val mutableBufferArray = ArrayBuffer[DataFrame]()
mutableBufferArray.append(hiveContext.emptyDataframe())

for loop {

              val interm = mergeDataFrame(df, mutableBufferArray.last)
              val intermSchema = interm.schema
              val intermRDD = interm.rdd.repartition(8)


              mutableBufferArray.append(hiveContext.createDataFrame(intermRDD, intermSchema))
              mutableBufferArray.remove(0)

}
```

This is how I **wrestle** tungsten into compliance.
By going from a DF to an RDD and back I end up with a real object rather than a whole tungsten generated process pipe from front to back.

In my code I iterate a few times before writing out to disk (50-150 iterations seem to work best). That's where I clear out the bufferArray again to start over fresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like this:

```
var df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).toDF()

for(i<- 1 to 200000) {
  val df_add = sc.parallelize(Seq(i)).toDF()
  df = df.unionAll(df_add)
}
```

Then df will have 400000 partitions afterwards, which makes the following actions inefficient (because you have 1 tasks for each partition).

Try to reduce the number of partitions to e.g. 200 before persisiting the dataframe (using e.g. `df.coalesce(200).write.saveAsTable(....)`)

Comment: I coalesce the output already, sorry I didn't mention that.
The problem here is when I update records in the dataframe (so not just appending with a union all)
So the runtime itself is already slowed down when persisting (in an attempt to not slow down)
Repartitioning doesn't help either.

Comment: to clarify what I mean; persisting or
Repartitioning during the iteration... it all results in the same thing (see image in question) coalesce at the end just move the problems to the point where I need to write out to HDFS